# how to disable acrobat reader contextmenu in Wpf?

Tags: wpf, acrobat, right-click

I'm showing PDF documents in my application using Acrobat ActiveX.
I want to know is it possible to disable right click on PDF documents?

Answer (score 0):

My previous solution didn't work, so there's another one. You just need to set a mouse hook on the child window that receives mouse notifications.

```
public class AcrobatReader : AxAcroPDF
{
    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;
    private const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;

    private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public AcrobatReader()
    {
        _hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, _proc, FindWindow(null, "avpageview"), 0);
    }

    ~AcrobatReader()
    {
        if (_hookID != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
            _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && (IntPtr)WM_RBUTTONDOWN == wParam)
        {
            return new IntPtr(1);
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
}
```

Comment: I did it the same but WM_RBUTTONDOWN event dosen't fire at all. I don't know why.

Comment: @r r, I've updated my answer with another solution that works.